# Partial derivative using Jacobian shortcut?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, jacobian

Let $x,y$ and $z$ be determined by $x+y^2=u, y+z^2=v$ and $z+x^2=w$. By writing $F=x+y^2-u, G=y+z^2-v$ and $H=z+x^2-w$ and using the quotient of Jacobian's 'shortcut' calculate. 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} 
\end{equation}
Confused what Jacobian's 'shortcut' is and why I cannot just rearrange the first equation to yield $x=u-y^2$ and then find the partial derivative of that.

Comment: do you mean Jacobi's? Jacobian is the matrix of partial derivatives